# How to set a tableview in JavaFX in initialize method

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, observablelist

Hi I'm new to JavaFX and want to populate a tableview with data

I use not the programmatic way I create the tableview with scene builder and have a controller file . I have a data file for the getters and setters already and created a observable list

```java
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML TableView<Bew> tableV;
    @FXML TableColumn<Bew, String> nameCol =new TableColumn<>("Name");
    @FXML TableColumn<Bew, String> dateCol =new TableColumn<>("Datum");
    @FXML TableColumn<Bew, String> actionCol =new TableColumn<>("Aktivität");
    @FXML TableColumn<Bew, String> infoCol =new TableColumn<>("Info");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        SQLiteDB DB = new SQLiteDB();
        ObservableList<Bew> list = DB.getData();
        tableV.setItems(list);
    }

public ObservableList<Bew> getData() {

        ObservableList<Bew> bewList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        bewList.add(new Bew("Rita", "01.12.1920", "Gespräch", "gud"));
        bewList.add(new Bew("Marc", "14.03.1930", "Spaziergang", "gud"));
        bewList.add(new Bew("Peter", "27.01.1901", "dfdsfdsfdsfdsf", "gud"));
        bewList.add(new Bew("John", "12.12.1912", "dfdsfdsfdsfdsf", "gud"));
        return bewList;
    }
```

When I run the code no error appears but no data in tableview

Any help?

Comment: [Can't populate JavaFX TableView created in SceneBuilder 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806367/cant-populate-javafx-tableview-created-in-scenebuilder-2)

Comment: Thank you I'm going to check up my code

Comment: This looks to me to be a fairly good tutorial: [Creating an Address Book with FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm)

Comment: Nice - thumbUp -

Comment: Initializing inhejected fields is a bad idea; remove those assignments or the `@FXML` annotations. Furthermore in code you did not set the `cellValueFactory`s of the columns. On the other hand they may be set in the fxml, which is why it's important to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have getter and setter in your Bow class